# Apache https is slow

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, https

*Update*
I switched to using a 1024 bit key, and I changed the SSLCipherSuite in my ssl.conf file.
SSLCipherSuite RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP

Hey,

I've set apache up to use SSL with a self signed certificate.

With https (KeepAlive on), I can get over 3000 requests per second.  However, with https (KeepAlive off), I can only get 13 requests per second.

I know there is supposed to be a bit of an overhead, but this seems abnormal.  Can anyone suggest how I might go about debugging this.

Here is the ab log for https:

```
Server Software:        Apache/2.2.3
Server Hostname:        127.0.0.1
Server Port:            443
SSL/TLS Protocol:       TLSv1/SSLv3,DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA,4096,256

Document Path:          /hello.html
Document Length:        29 bytes

Concurrency Level:      5
Time taken for tests:   30.49425 seconds
Complete requests:      411
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      119601 bytes
HTML transferred:       11919 bytes
Requests per second:    13.68 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       365.565 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       73.113 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          3.86 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:      190  347  74.3    333     716
Processing:     0   14  24.0      1     166
Waiting:        0   11  21.6      0     165
Total:        191  361  80.8    345     716

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    345
  66%    377
  75%    408
  80%    421
  90%    468
  95%    521
  98%    578
  99%    596
 100%    716 (longest request)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the time is being used by the RSA computation required for the SSL handshake.  You have selected a very large RSA key (4096 bits).  You may want to also verify that your client is properly using SSL resume sessions.

Comment: Yes, that was part of it.  I also needed to change the SSLCipherSuite.

Answer (score 0):

Check SSLRandomSeed. You should not be using /dev/random (unless your OS don't block on not enough entropy).

Also check if you're using a session cache. If not, then enable one (check SSLSessionCache).